# Subring of number field is Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I've been trying to prove that every subring $R$ of a number field $K$ is a Noetherian ring. I'm aware that of a proof when $K = \mathbb{Q}$ using the fact that every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}$. However, this fact crucially uses that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, hence only answers my question in a special case. By Hilbert's basis theorem, I've been able to prove the result when $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra. Beyond that, I'm stuck.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/19523/5091)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Traditionally, "Number field" means subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$. E.g., that's the definition in Daniel Marcus's *Number Fields*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I claim that for any prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, the quotient $R/pR$ is finite dimensional as an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.  Indeed, suppose $x_1,\dots,x_n\in R$ have images in $R/pR$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  I claim that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are then linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and hence over $\mathbb{Q}$), so $n\leq [K:\mathbb{Q}]$.  Indeed, suppose that $\sum a_kx_k=0$ for some integers $a_k$ which are not all $0$.  Let $m$ be maximal such that $p^m\mid a_k$ for all $k$.  Then $\sum \frac{a_k}{p^m}x_k=0$ as well, and some $\frac{a_k}{p^m}$ is not divisible by $p$.  We can then take this equation mod $p$ to get a linear dependence between the images of the $x_k$ in $R/pR$, which is a contradiction.

So $R/pR$ is finite for any prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$.  It follows that $p^mR/p^{m+1}R$ is finite for all $m$ (since it is a cyclic $R/pR$-module) and thus $R/p^mR$ is finite by induction on $m$.  By the Chinese remainder theorem it follows that $R/nR$ is finite for any nonzero integer $n$.

Now note that any nonzero $a\in R$ is a divisor (in $R$) of some nonzero integer.  Indeed, if $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f(a)=0$ says that $a$ divides the constant term of $f$.  It follows that $R/aR$ is finite since it is a quotient of $R/nR$ for some nonzero integer $n$.

So, for any nonzero $a\in R$, there are only finitely many ideals of $R$ that contain $aR$.  That is, every nonzero ideal of $R$ is contained in only finitely many other ideals.  It follows that $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: This is one of the finest answers I've ever read on this site. The ideas involved are presented so naturally, but they are also beautiful and creative. A masterpiece!